# What are some 3rd party mini-figure gun makers that distribute in Canada?

Tags: shopping, 3rd-party

I'd like to buy some flint-lock era mini-figure guns for my collection, something like [these](http://www.brickforge.com/store/product.php?productid=16949&cat=419&page=1) [guns](http://www.brickforge.com/store/product.php?productid=16947&cat=418&page=1). What I don't want is to pay the outrageous customs fees to get them to Canada. Does anyone know of either some Canadian makers or Canadian distributors?

Comment: Please do a simple research before asking a question.

Comment: @pcantin I did do some research before-hand. I knew of the brick republic website talked about in one of the answer, but it is only a distributor of some of the BrickArms line, and does not seem to have any of the flint-lock era type of guns that I described in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never paid customs fees on orders from [BrickForge](http://www.brickforge.com) or [BrickArms](http://www.brickarms.com). The key is to ship via the US Postal Service. Shipping via couriers like UPS usually results in customs brokerage fees which is what drives up the cost.

Answer (score 2):

I simply [googled](http://www.google.ca/search?rlz=1C1CHFX_enCA450CA450&gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=custom%20lego%20bricks%20canada) and found [brickrepublic](http://www.brickrepublic.com/servlet/StoreFront) based in Pointe-Claire, Qc

Trick : I usually arrange with visiting/traveling folks to bring small packages in Canada and avoid the outrageous custom fees.

Comment: I knew about BrickRepublic before, and it seems to have a nice collection. But, as I talked about in another comment, it does not carry the type of guns I described, sorry.

Comment: If you're that picky, you can certainly afford the custom fees. ;p

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [Modern Brick Warfare](http://modernbrickwarfare.com). They have a ton of custom LEGO-compatible weapons.